# Как вывести детей определённого родителя, функцией wp_list_pages?

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет! Взял функцию с документации, однако я не совсем понял, как указать ID конкретного родителя. Прошу помочь!

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {
  while ( have_posts() ) {
         the_post();
$children = wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0' );
if ( $children) : ?>
    <ul>
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;

  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Вы взяли код из конкретного [примера](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_pages#4-1-vyvedem-spisok-dochernih-stranits), с чем конкретно у Вас возникли проблемы? Там где у Вас `$post->ID` там и указывается ID конкретного родителя.

Comment: пробовал прописать так 

wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&child_of='.$post->1148.'&echo=0' );

но это не правильно. Как указать ID?

Comment: `wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=1148&echo=0');` если указываете конкретное ID, не нужно указывать `$post`. $post` -- это объект, но я так понимаю Вам это ничего не скажет, потому вместо `$post->ID` просто указываете `1148` как я уже написал выше.

Comment: "но я так понимаю Вам это ничего не скажет"   -   скажет! Я просто с id ошибся, извиняюсь!   Я пробовал ваш вариант с самого начала. Но спасибо, что написали ещё раз, как надо! Я после вашего ответа начал перепроверять id
И ещё... подскажите пожалуйста, а как добавить sup в тег li, чтобы получилось так?
<li><sup>1</sup><a href="">proiecte</a></li>

Comment: А `<sup>1</sup>` в конкретном случае является чем? Вообще есть два варианта, использовать фильтр [wp_list_pages](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_list_pages) или использовать кастомный walker который будет наследовать `Walker_Page`.